# Migrating Drupal Site from one Theme to Another

Tags: drupal, migrating

I am not a drupal expert but would appreciate any help.

I would love to move all my site files, modules, views, contents, nodes, configurations, blocks, taxonomy, rules, images, file systems, and reports from the current site into the new theme without losing out on anything. what are the steps?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try to put the theme folder into `sites/all/themes` and then just turn it on through Appearence on your site?

Comment: It is redirecting you to localhost because you had clean URL module turned on on the old site. The new server cannot find those clean URLs. Click the green wamp icon (I assume you use wamp), and then go to 'Apache -> Apache Modules and tick the rewrite_module. Then refresh the page. It should work. If you are not using wamp, you can do the same on any other server.

Comment: Hello, I have enable the rewrite module and it works fine. But my challenge is the migration. The above solutions never seems to work, is there any other means? Can we take it out from here. please send me an email to dolpaz02@yahoo.com so we can discuss more about this.. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dir "/sites/all/themes" you have your current theme. Or it's empty if you are using some default Drupal theme.
 So if I got you right you just want to replace the current theme and keep the rest of the site. In that case copy your new theme in the same dir ("/sites/all/themes"), clear the cache (admin menu: Configuration->Development->Performance) and go to Appearance page (again from admin menu). Now if your new theme is ok you should see it here. Enable it, set as default, clear the cache again if you have to and you should be using your new theme now.

So, basically, you just have to add you new theme's file, clear the cache and activate new theme.

Comment: Hello MilanG, thank you for the amazing response. I will do just as you've rightly said and revert.

Comment: Hello MilanG, I tried the above solution and it scattered my site. I cleared the cache twice, yet it never worked. I had to drop my db and re-import twice. is there any medium i can contact you. my email is dolpaz02@yahoo.com. hoping to read from you soonest !

Comment: Hello Adeniji. You can always activate your old theme back. Just go to Appearance again, make old theme default again and clear the cache again if you have to. Themes can not support all the features you'll ever need for your site - just some "standard" features.
Also, I don't understand why you dropped your database? Theme has nothing to do with database?! Theme is just defining how pages presented by your site look and point of having different themes is to be able to switch design but without changing content.